# Анимация прокрутки страницы

Tags: html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте! Возникла такая проблема. Нужна [такая](https://codyhouse.co/gem/page-scroll-effects/) или похожая анимация прокрутки страницы, но есть одна проблема. Один из блоков больше 100vh в высоту и когда пользователь прокрутит на этот блок у него должна быть возможность скролить его как обычную страницу. Есть у кого примеры или где почитать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скрипт этой страницы перехватывает события скроллинга, поэтому через свойство `overflow` сделать это проблематично. Можно подключить кастомный скрипт скроллинга, например [вот этот](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) неплохой.

Здесь возникает обратная проблема - скроллинг блока может блокировать смену разделов, потому его стоит делать не во всю ширину, а оставить место для контроллера.

Вот [пример](http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=gf15ae5ffc2e8c7749997963530d33acfef3bbd491) на основе демо-страницы вашего скрипта. Некоторые изменения внесены в файл style.css, см. комментарии.

Comment: Спасибо, большое! Помогло.